# Can onenote have runners

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-onenote

Is there a way to make OneNote recognize snippet of code (of tsql) and execute sample (top 50 of the select) of the output and include the answer like jupyter for python?

a. Native method to run a batch file and attach an the artifact response
b. A Plug in that will wrap the a top section and attach a response on the bottom section?

Comment: Not natively.  You would need an add-in for that functionality.  I am not sure if one exists or not, though.

Comment: No. One Note is not a programming tool.  You would need to search for a 3rd party App if one exists.

Comment: That is the question. does anyone know if there is a way, Native or 3rd party app. If there is, what it is called.

Comment: You need to search for a 3rd party tool.  What is normally available does not work with One Note.